# Uses of the ASP Parameter objects

Tags: asp.net

Everyone,

I've been brushing up on some seldom used controls (at least for me) and I ran across the Parameter controls (ControlParameter, CookieParameter, etc.)

It seems they are mostly used with the SQL Datasource control, or the Object Datasource control.

But, is there any other uses that they can be put too?  Or, are they fairly useless unless you are using the two Datasource controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was only build for the data source controls, but certainly you could reuse them for your own purposes, if you wanted to create your own custom control.  It's essentially a class, so that would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is used only with DataSources of one sort or another.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> You can use the ControlParameter class to bind the value of a Control
>   property, such as SelectedValue or SelectedIndex, to a parameter that
>   is used in a parameterized SQL query, business object method, or
>   filtering expression.